# Find SOAPAction from a WSDL

Tags: android, web-services, soap, wsdl, android-ksoap2

My requirement is to call a web service from Android and display the result in a nice manner.

But inside the web service's WSDL I don't find a `SOAPAction`. The WSDL  looks like this:

```
<operation name="getStudentList">
 <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
 <input>
   <soap:body use="literal"/>
 </input>
 <output>
   <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </output>
</operation>
```

Is there any way to find the `SOAPAction` in some other places inside the WSDL? Can I call the web service and get a result without the `SOAPAction`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `SOAPAction` is required for SOAP 1.1 over HTTP but it's hard to say what the behavior of your web service will be if you don't send a proper header. The web service may return a fault if it's missing the `SOAPAction` (or if it has an unexpected value) or it might do nothing at all.

The WSDL is the place to find the value to use for the `SOAPAction`, inside the `<soap:operation>`. If it's not specified for an operation or it's like in the example you posted (`soapAction=""`) you normally need to add this to the request headers:

```
SOAPAction: ""
```

Try with an empty quoted string and it should work.