# How to call Web Service with empty soapAction definition?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, maximo

I received WSDL file from my customer for integrations and that WSDL file was used for other customers and integrations also so it is valid and it won't be changed certainly.

I call Web Service from some IBM application (Java based) where I define in some application parameters:end point URL, Service Name and Soap Action. This definition is not done in code but on GUI. I also did many integrations before so this is how it works.

Now I am confused:
I have end Point URL, I have Service Name (...HttpBinding) I have name of the operation in WSDL file (sendSMS) but field SOAP ACTION is empty? This Service has other operations too so I must call this operation sendSMS but how to define soapaction when it is blank?

Once again WSDL generation won't be changed it is valid and used by others before. I am confused if some one can give me answer. How to find out soap action name?

this is from WSDL:

```
    <operation name="sendSms">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
```

**UPDATE:**

This is the possible list of parameters which I can define in IBM Tivoli Maximo application. In previous integrations I defined only three at that was enough `(ENDPOINTURL, SERVICENAME, SOAPACTION).`

```
CFGXMLPATH
ENDPOINTURL
HTTPCONNTIMEOUT
HTTPREADTIMEOUT
HTTPVERSION
MEP
PASSWORD
SERVICENAME
SOAPACTION
SOAPVERSION
USERNAME
WSEXIT
```

That is the possible list of parameters which can be populate on GUI.
Here is the part from WSDL just to show you that I have several operations.

```
<binding name="CpaSmsSendServiceWSExport_SmsParlayxSHttpBinding" type="tns:SmsParlayxS">
    <soap:binding style="document" 
transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>>

    <operation name="getRequestId">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/><input><soap:body parts="getRequestId"/>
<soap:header message="tns:SmsParlayx_getRequestId" part="potpis">
                </soap:header></input><output><soap:body parts="getRequestIdResponse" use="literal"/></output></operation>


    <operation name="sendBulkSms">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/><input><soap:body parts="sendBulkSms"/>
<soap:header message="tns:SmsParlayx_sendBulkSms" part="potpis">
                </soap:header></input><output><soap:body parts="sendBulkSmsResponse" use="literal"/></output></operation>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274644/find-soapaction-from-a-wsdl

Comment: It is not duplicate!!!! I have several operations in that WSDL while previous post had only one! How to web service knows which oepration to call if I put only "" in soapAction.????? Bogdane stvarno vas zelim zamoliti da ne govorite odmah da je duplikat ako mi vec ne mozete pomoci za ovaj veliki problem koji imam...nije u redu..hvala

Comment: It is not duplicate!!!!!!!!!!!! Previous post had only one operation while I have  5 operations in WSDL so how will web service know what operation/action to call if I put just ""???? Bogdane nije duplikat i stvarno vas zelim zamoliti da ako mi ne mozete pomoci ne govoirte tako lako da je duplikat za nesto sto mi predstavlja veliki problem..nije u redu.. hvala

Comment: The operation to call can be found in the first element of `<soap:Body>`. `SOAPAction` can be used to indicate the intent of the SOAP HTTP request and have your server perform some action without the need to look inside the `<soap:Body>`. If it's empty then there is no indication of the intent of the message. `SOAPAction` can be used when you have overloaded operations or when your payload is generic and ...

Comment: ... you need a way to direct the message within your server. Your `SOAPAction` is empty so there is no intent expressed. The operation name inside `<soap:Body>` is the operation you are calling. Here is a another link you might want to read: http://michelchristianen.blogspot.ro/2011/02/understanding-soapaction-mystery_5785.html

Comment: I  updated my question. You may now see the whole picture- I gave you the list of parameters (as I said usually populate only  three paramteres to invoke web service and that was enough) and I gave you the example 2 of 5 operations in WSDL - so how to invoke second operation sendBulkSms when I have five of them. If you can give me the example how would you invoke this operation based on the wsdl and the parameter list which exist? Thank you!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely legal as the WS-I Profile, so it should be supported by your IBM toll also

Comment: OK so what should I populate and in what parameter field ??? I once again mention that web service has many operations so how it will know which operation to call??